# How to make the summation sign wider?

Tags: math-operators, scaling

I would like to make the following summation sign as wide as the subscript (but not taller) in the display mode:

```
\[ \sum_{i_1, i_2,\cdots,i_m=1}^n\]
```

Comment: Please clarify whether you use display or inline math, best by providing a MWE.

Comment: By "wide enough", do you mean "as wide as the subscript"?

Comment: yes. As wide as the subscript and if not possible as wide as possible.

Comment: In display math. I edited the question.

Comment: BTW, the ellipsis should be on the base line: `\dots` instead of `\cdots`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you want something like this

[image: oh, that's awful!]

or

[image]

### Code for the first image

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\widesum}[2]{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\dowidesum{#1}{#2}}}}_{#1}^{#2}
}
\newcommand{\dowidesum}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$\scriptstyle#1$}%
  \dimen0=\wd0
  \sbox0{$\scriptstyle#2$}%
  \ifdim\wd0>\dimen0 \dimen0=\wd0\fi
  \resizebox{\dimen0}{\height}{$\displaystyle\sum$}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\widesum{i_1, i_2,\cdots,i_m=1}{n}
\]

\end{document}
```

### Code for the second image

Just change `\height` into `!`

## Better?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{\substack{1\le i_k\le n\\1\le k\le m}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xparse` embellishments for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l_tmpc_box
\cs_new:Nn \dim_max:nnn
{
  \dim_max:nn { \dim_max:nn { #1 } { #2 } } { #3 }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \dowidesum { m m }
{
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { $\mathsurround=0pt\scriptstyle#1$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpb_box { $\mathsurround=0pt\scriptstyle#2$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpc_box { $\mathsurround=0pt\displaystyle\sum$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim
  {
    \dim_max:nnn
    { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
    { \box_wd:N \l_tmpb_box }
    { \box_wd:N \l_tmpc_box }
  }
  \box_resize_to_wd_and_ht:Nnn \l_tmpc_box { \l_tmpa_dim } { \box_ht:N \l_tmpc_box }
  \mathop{\box_use:N \l_tmpc_box}\limits\sp{#1}\sb{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand \widesum {e{^_}}
{
  \dowidesum{#1}{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\[ \widesum_{i_1, i_2,\cdots,i_m=1}^n \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The syntax for the `e` specifier will soon be changing, stay tuned.

Comment: Embellishment???

Comment: @Bernard That's what the L3 team calls these `e`-type arguments.

Comment: @HenriMenke The change to `e` arguments have been deployed; you should directly define `\widesum` with argument list `e{^_}` (and the same replacement text as `\dowidesum`).

Comment: @egreg This doesn't quite work because `_` has catcode 12 inside `\ExplSyntaxOn...Off`.  But I adapted the rest of the syntax.